# How to provide access to specific plugin to all the user roles except subscriber in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am using ultimate [Product Catalog plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-product-catalogue/) in WordPress. Currently only Administrator role users are able to view the plugin settings.

But I need Editor, Contributor, and Author role users also has to have access to view the specific plugin. Can anyone please provide me the solution to grant access to view the specific plug-in.

Comment: what do you mean by specific plugin? the settings of it?

Comment: @DavidLee - Generally wordpress has multiple plugins installed. But i do not want to display all the plugins for Contributor role user. I just want to display once specific plugin to users, so that they can enter into that plugin  and do their actions(configurations/settings of that plugin) related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Got a fix for this. 
Get current user id and based on ID get current user info.From that user info get user role. If user role is not subscriber then only we can add menu page. This way editors/contributors can access plugin.

Below is the working code.

```
<?php
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
    $user = new WP_User($userID);
    $userRole =  $user->roles[0];
    if($userRole!="subscriber")
    {
    $Access_Role =$userRole;      
    $UPCP_Menu_page = add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $Access_Role, 'UPCP-options', 'UPCP_Output_Options',null , '50.5');
    add_action("load-$UPCP_Menu_page", "UPCP_Screen_Options");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )` which applies to any logged in user above subscriber. Also, check out WordPress roles and capabilities to see other permissions for various levels.

```
<?php
if( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
  // do whatever
}
```

Comment: I places this code in main.php file of the plugin. It is giving an error while executing. It is giving an error as "Error evaluating code" current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ).

Answer (score 0):

issue with making such a change is if you edit the plugin code, you will lose your changes the next time the plugin updates.

a better thing to do is, figure out if the plugin is creating it's own capabilities, then create a small plugin with the sole purpose of giving said capabilities to anyone who is not "subscriber"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Am stopping automatic update install for that specific plugin so it will solve issue of losing custom changes. Now i need to display this specific plugin  to all the user roles except subscriber in word press.